# 'MediaMetadata' is not defined no-undef and MediaMetadata is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webapi, howler.js, mediasession

I've implemented playlist player using howler.js in vuejs. I want to integrate `MediaMetadata` API to it. `MediaSession` API is working fine with controls like notification bar, keyboard controls, remote devices. But I'm unable to set audio's metadata(title,artist,album,artwork) using MediaMetadata.
Followed the [tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaMetadata) given [github repo](https://github.com/mdn/browser-compat-data).

Getting below error:
`error 'MediaMetadata' is not defined no-undef`

I'm using `chrome 57` to run it. Also tested browser compatibility with following code :

```
if ('mediaSession' in navigator) {
    console.log("Browser supports MediaMetadata API")
    navigator.mediaSession.metadata = new MediaMetadata({
      title: "my_track_name",
      artist: "track_artist_name",
      album: "track_album_name",
      artwork: "track_image",
    });

} else {
    console.log("Your browser doean't support MediaMetadata")
}
```

Above code prints `Browser supports MediaMetadata API`, but it continuously throwing error `MediaMetadata is not defined`.

I had also tried to import it from package `@mdn/browser-compat-data` like following :

```
const MediaMetadata = require("@mdn/browser-compat-data").api.MediaMetadata;
```

Now, it's showing below error :
`Uncaught TypeError: MediaMetadata is not a constructor`.

Also tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62264777/9779592) solution but no luck, error continues.

Can anyone plese help me with this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Fixed it by using `new window.MediaMetadata({})` instead of `new MediaMetadata({})`